# Need two url in p-panel primeng , in the one item

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I need two url in my item of p-panelMenu .

TypeScript

```
export class AppComponent {
  items: MenuItem[];

     ngOnInit() {
        this.items = [
          {
            label: 'File',
            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-file',
            items: [
              {
                label: 'New',
                icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-plus',
                items: [
                  {
                    label: 'Video',
                    icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-video',
                    url : 'google.com'
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ];
     }
   }
```

HTML

```
<p-panelMenu [model]="items"></p-panelMenu>
```

how can add another element (icon or button) in this item and another url for that?

[image: Like This]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can add styleClass:'custom-css' to the specific object which you want to add the class and then write custom css

   :host ::ng-deep .custom-css{
   width: 50%;
   display: inline-block;
   }